# Override data in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mixins, vuejs2

I'm using a mixin to add and override vue data.  I am able to add new data, but I cannot seem to override existing data.  Here is the simple code:

```
var mixin = {
    data: function() {
    return {
      foo: 'boo',
      test: 'blah'
    }
  }
}

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  mixins: [mixin],
  data: function() {
    return {
      foo: 'bar'
    }
  }
});
```

When I run it, 'test' equals 'blah' properly, but 'foo' still equals 'bar'.  Is there anyway to have a mixin override existing vue data in addition to adding new data?

Here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/8v9sfxok/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some have mentioned, mixins cannot override existing data.  For this I had to take my original component and make it a "base" component.  Then use the "extends" option in another component to override existing data.

Answer (score 2):

From the [mixins documentations](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Option-Merging):

> Options that expect object values ... will be merged into the same
> object. The **component’s options will take priority when there are
> conflicting keys in these objects**

(emphasis mine).

If you want a different merge strategy, [you can define one](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Custom-Option-Merge-Strategies).

Answer (score 0):

One way around this is to create a method in your mixin and invoke that from your template:

**html:**

```
<div id="vue-instance">
  <p>
  {{getFoo()}}
  </p>
  <p>
  {{test}}
  </p>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var mixin = {
    data: function() {
    return {
      foo: 'baz',
      test: 'blah'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getFoo: function () {
        return 'baz';
    }
  }
}

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  mixins: [mixin],
  data: function() {
    return {
      foo: 'bar'
    }
  }
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dwsx78n9/)